# Preventing the creation of empty cells

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I have a table with cells who's values come from the output fields of a SQL query. The cells use this piece of code in the *expression' menu:

```
=Iif(Fields!Reference_Name.Value="BR1HTWLPH",Fields!Percent_in_spec.Value,System.DBNull.Value)
```

When it runs, the code creates roughly 500 empty cells; one for each line in the `Reference_Name` field where there is no match. I'm only interested in having the cell that contains the match; is there a way to prevent the empty cells from being created, or to hide cells *based only on the cell's value*?

Edit: This is example code for the first cell only. I have 500+ different reference names. Each one will have code similar to the code above, but with `BR1HTWLPH` replaced with its own unique reference name.

Comment: Can you add a WHERE clause to the SQL statement that only brings in records where the *Reference_Name* is "BR1HTWLPH"?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Only the first cell will have that reference name; all cells will have their own specific one.I edited my submission to reflect this.

Comment: Do you have anything other than hard coded values to do the matching against?

Comment: @MikeD I have hard-coded reference names, but I could code in whatever I'd need to get a solution working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issues I was having. I changed the expression for the cells in my table to be `=Max(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Iif(Fields!Reference_Name.Value = "NameValue", Fields!Percent_in_spec.Value, 0))`. 
Since this expression doesn't output multiple values per instance, like my last expression, I don't end up with multiple null cells that need to be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding row grouping on Reference_Name and in Group properties you can set filter on Reference_Name like  Reference_Name="BR1HTWLPH" or Reference_Name.Value <> ""

[image: Group Properties]

I believe that will solve the pupose.

Comment: I tried your answer, but nothing changed. The field `Reference_Name` has no null entries; only the cells it outputs into do, because of how I've formatted my `IIF` statement.